# Colour scale in c++

Tags: c++, colors

I have an array of float values from -1 to 1.
I want to get a gradient colour scale red-yellow-green-blue-purple, where colour depends on magnitude of value( 1 is for red, -1 is for blue, 0 is for green?).

How should I process these values to get rgb for any of them?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want a linear interpolating gradient, then you can do this for each variable in the array. `r`, `g`, `b`, will be in the range 0..1, and you can easily convert that to 0..255 integers if you need to.

```
float v; // = array value
float r = 0.f, g = 0.f, b = 0.f;
if (v < 0)
{
    b = 1.f + v;
    g = -v;
}
else 
{
    r = v;
    g = 1.f - v;
}
```